# How to Get RowID(TR id) form TD Id

Tags: javascript

I have TD Id.But i need to get TR id using TD id .How can i get.

Help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tr` is the parent node of the `td`:

```
var tableRowId = document.getElementById("id_of_td").parentNode.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

TR is TD's parent node, so you need to do:

```
    var trId=document.getElementById(tdId).parentNode.id;
```